# Javascript get array field name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I access the field name "DateAndTime" from the below array, I need to format the json Date output correctly. Any advice/assistance would be appreciated.

```
var chartData = [{"Value1":17.800,"DateAndTime":"\/Date(1338501601000)\/"}]
```

Comment: Looks like Nelson wrote it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
alert( chartData[0].DateAndTime );
```

But take care you are lacking an ending `]` in your posted code.

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/81e90).

Answer (score 1):

You would do this:

```
chartData[0].DateAndTime;
```